# Retrieving rows that have different values for a column in unnormalized table

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Given the following fruit table, I wanted to write sql query that returns Fruits that have rating of both A and B. In the example, the answer should give Orange and Lemon since they have both A & B ratings. Apple & Pear, though they have A and B rating, they should not be included in the result as they don't contain both. One way to go about is to use stored procedure, but I wanted to write sql statement that is extensible to any number of ratings (not only A & B).

```
Fruit     Rating
Orange      A
Orange      B
Orange      C
Lemon       A
Lemon       B
Pear        B
Pear        C
Pear        C
Apple       A
Apple       C
```

Expected result:

```
Fruit    Rating
Orange      A
Orange      B
Lemon       A
Lemon       B
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: The query should run for both

Comment: @Michael, what do you want to say when you say this "extensible to any number of ratings (not only A & B)" ? Can you explain more ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBoka, to mean that the universal set of ratings is not bounded, i.e., A,B,C,D, .....

Comment: @Michael I understand that but what do you expect from query ? It is static...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Oracle. It requires support for DISTINCT in window functions.

```
with data (Fruit,Rating) as (
  select 'Orange', 'A' from dual union all
  select 'Orange', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'Orange', 'C' from dual union all
  select 'Lemon', 'A' from dual union all
  select 'Lemon', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'Pear', 'B' from dual union all
  select 'Pear', 'C' from dual union all
  select 'Pear', 'C' from dual union all
  select 'Apple', 'A' from dual union all
  select 'Apple', 'C' from dual
)
select fruit, rating
from (
  select fruit, rating, cnt, max(cnt) over() max_cnt
  from (
    select fruit, rating,
      count(distinct rating) over(partition by fruit) cnt
    from data where rating in ('A','B')
  )
)
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Fruit
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Rating IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
    GROUP BY Fruit
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Rating) = 3
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Fruit IN (SELECT Fruit FROM cte) AND Rating IN ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

Comment: Okay, but seems like I need to supply the number of ratings (3 in this case ) for evaluation. And when I need to query two ratings then I need to change 3 to 2.

Comment: @Michael You might need some dynamic SQL to do exactly what you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! and on closer look the query fails to retrieve values with duplicate entries because of the use of distinct. For example, trying to retrieve fruits that has two A ratings and B, i.e. 'A','A'. & 'B'

Comment: @Michael No, that isn't true, and I stand by the code I wrote above.  My answer would _not_ return a fruit which only has a rating of `A`, if you are searching for both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yeah, it will work if you use distinct ratings like A, B, ... but say you want to retrieve fruits that has two A ratings and B. This won't work because use are using `DISTINCT Rating`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you did not understood what OP wanted to tell you...

Comment: @Michael What you are describing now is really a different question, which needs a different query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:
I have updated my answer because of this comment "Your query would return a fruit which has an A rating twice." from Tim Biegeleisen . Thanks!

```
select * 
from FTable
where fruit in (
select Fruit
   from FTable
   group by Fruit
   having sum(case when rating = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 
   and sum(case when rating = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) = 1)
and rating in ('A', 'B');
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31f7232dabb448f8149262d992d1348f)

**RESULT:**

```
  |  FRUIT  |  RATING  |
  +---------+----------+ 
  |  Orange |  A       |
  |  Orange |  B       |
  |  Lemon  |  A       |
  |  Lemon  |  B       |
```

And if you want to get the Fruits that have more than one A rating with B rating and other way around then use this:

```
select * 
from FTable
where fruit in (
select Fruit
   from FTable
   group by Fruit
   having max(case when rating = 'A' then 'A' else '' end) = 'A' 
   and max(case when rating = 'B' then 'B' else '' end) = 'B')
and rating in ('A', 'B')
group by Fruit, rating;
```

And here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ce6d191f8ef3a83206c5181b0dd9c9c) for that

Comment: Can the query be restructured not to use literal value like 2?

Comment: And what should 2 represent in your example ? Number of letters in Rating (if A and B then 2 if A and B and C then 3 ?)

Comment: Your query would return a fruit which has an `A` rating twice.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, you are correct 100%. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient method is to use `exists`:

```
select fr.*
from fruitrating fr
where (fr.rating = 'A' and
       exists (select 1 from fruitrating fr2 where fr2.fruit = fr.fruit and fr2.rating = 'B'
              )
      ) or
      (fr.rating = 'B' and
       exists (select 1 from fruitrating fr2 where fr2.fruit = fr.fruit and fr2.rating = 'A'
              )
      ) ;
```

You can actually simplify this logic to:

```
select fr.*
from fruitrating fr
where (fr.rating in ('A', 'B') and
       exists (select 1 
               from fruitrating fr2
               where fr2.fruit = fr.fruit and
                     fr2.rating in ('A', 'B') and
                     fr2.rating <> fr.rating
              )
      ) ;
```

However, this does not generalize as easily to larger combinations.

If you just wanted the fruits and not the rows, then:

```
select fruit
from fruitrating
where rating in ('A', 'B')
group by fruit
having count(rating) = 2;
```

Use `count(distinct rating)` if the table can have duplicates.